# My virtual host in xampp isn't working for laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp, virtualhost

i've set my virtual hosts in xampp for laravel

httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/shareitbaby.io/public"
ServerName www.shareitbaby.io
ServerAlias shareitbaby.io
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/shareitbaby.io/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and my host file:

```
127.0.0.1 shareitbaby.io    
::1 shareitbaby.io
```

and when i type shareitbaby.io it's not working

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to ping your domain first, DNS errors usually indicate there is a problem with hosts file or browser cached different IP for this domain. Apache config looks ok, this error indicates that request didn't reach Apache server.

Comment: please try by changing serverName and ServerAlias like below
     
     `ServerName   shareitbaby.io
     ServerAlias     www.shareitbaby.io`